# PyQt event emmitted twice

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals

I'm trying to implement drag-n-drop'in' items from `QListWidget` to `QGraphicsView`. I've inherited my own class `MooView` from `QGraphicsView` and encapsulated `dragMove`, `dragEnter` and `drop` events. But while testing this out, i've noticed that each event is emmitted twice.

Here's my `MooView` code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MooView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)

        self.handlers = {}

        self.handlers['dragEnter'] = []
        self.handlers['dragEnter'].append(super(MooView, self).dragEnterEvent)

        self.handlers['dragLeave'] = []
        self.handlers['dragLeave'].append(super(MooView, self).dragLeaveEvent)

        self.handlers['dragMove'] = []
        self.handlers['dragMove'].append(super(MooView, self).dragMoveEvent)

        self.handlers['drop'] = []
        self.handlers['drop'].append(super(MooView, self).dropEvent)

    def addDragEnterHandler(self, handler):
        self.handlers['dragEnter'].append(handler)

    def removeDragEnterHandler(self, handler):
        self.handlers['dragEnter'].remove(handler)

    def addDragLeaveHandler(self, handler):
        self.handlers['dragLeave'].append(handler)

    def removeDragLeaveHandler(self, handler):
        self.handlers['dragLeave'].remove(handler)

    def addDragMoveHandler(self, handler):
        self.handlers['dragMove'].append(handler)

    def removeDragMoveHandler(self, handler):
        self.handlers['dragMove'].remove(handler)

    def addDropHandler(self, handler):
        self.handlers['drop'].append(handler)

    def removeDropHandler(self, handler):
        self.handlers['drop'].remove(handler)

        # handlers

    def dragEnterEvent(self, arg):
        #res = super(MooView, self).dragEnterEvent(arg)

        for h in self.handlers['dragEnter']:
            h(arg)

        #return res

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, arg):
        #res = super(MooView, self).dragLeaveEvent(arg)

        for h in self.handlers['dragLeave']:
            h(arg)

        #return res

    def dragMoveEvent(self, arg):
        #res = super(MooView, self).dragMoveEvent(arg)

        for h in self.handlers['dragMove']:
            h(arg)

        #return res

    def dropEvent(self, arg):
        #res = super(MooView, self).dropEvent(arg)

        for h in self.handlers['drop']:
            h(arg)

        #return res
```

And this is how i run that core:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtOpenGL
from window import Ui_MainWindow

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Hello, Qt!')

        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        self.ui.workspace_view.setScene(self.scene)

        rect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1000, 1000)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, rect.width(), rect.height())

        self.ui.workspace_view.setViewport(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget())

        icon = QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Images/50.png"))
        text = "50's element"
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(icon, text)
        self.ui.element_list.addItem(item)

        icon = QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Images/40.png"))
        text = "40's element"
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(icon, text)
        self.ui.element_list.addItem(item)

        self.ui.workspace_view.addDragEnterHandler(self.workspace_item_drag_enter)
        self.ui.workspace_view.addDragMoveHandler(self.workspace_item_drag_move)
        self.ui.workspace_view.addDropHandler(self.workspace_item_dropped)

    def workspace_item_drag_move(self, e):
        #print("item drag move")

        e.accept()

    def workspace_item_drag_enter(self, e):
        print("item drag enter")

        e.accept()

    def workspace_item_dropped(self, e):
        print("item dropped")

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp = Main()
    myApp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When drag-n-dropping items, "item drag enter" and "item dropped" lines are printed twice each in the terminal, e.g.:

```
item drag enter 
item drag enter 
item dropped 
item dropped
```

**The question is:** how it could be fixed???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i've read somewhere in the web, `QGraphicsView` could pass events to its `QGraphicsScene` in some cases. So it did here: when i inherited my class from `QGraphicsScene` and used it as default for `QGraphicsView` (replaced `MooView` with `QGraphicsView`; read the rest of this answer for details) it worked as i was expecting.

So, now i have two source parts: `MooGraphicsScene.py` and `main.py`. Here are they, respectively:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MooGraphicsScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, parent)

    def dragMoveEvent(selfs, e):
        pass

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        print("Drop fired!")

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()
        print("Drag entered!")
```

And this one:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtOpenGL
from window import Ui_MainWindow
from MooGraphicsScene import MooGraphicsScene

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Hello, Qt!')

        # Setup Workspace
        self.scene = MooGraphicsScene()
        self.ui.workspace_view.setScene(self.scene)

        rect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1000, 1000)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, rect.width(), rect.height())

        icon = QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Images/50.png"))
        text = "50's element"
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(icon, text)
        self.ui.element_list.addItem(item)

        icon = QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Images/40.png"))
        text = "40's element"
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(icon, text)
        self.ui.element_list.addItem(item)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp = Main()
    myApp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hope, this would help someone!