# qt+pyqt emitted dropped URL twice

Tags: qt, python-3.x, drag-and-drop, pyqt5

I've used QT-Designer to create a xml-File, which contains a LineEdit widget. In the script i've tried to emit the file-path via drag-drop. It works but st. is wrong: the url will be emitted twice and looks like:

/D:/Qtfile:///D:/Qt

i know similar topics like [PyQt event emmitted twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424404/pyqt-event-emmitted-twice) are discussed in stackoverflow. but i cannot find my answer...maybe i miss it. Why twice? Why the first "file://" disappeared?

If i dont use Qt-Designer and define a SubClass for drag-drop a text like class CustomEditLine(QLineEdit):... and then make the instance of QlineEdit in the main-Window, url will be emitted only once but still "/D:/Qt". 
here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject,QEvent
import sys

qtCreatorFile=".\\gui\\testdrop.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class QDropHandler(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QDropHandler, self).__init__(parent) 

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.DragEnter:
            event.accept()
        if event.type() == QEvent.Drop:
            md = event.mimeData()
            if md.hasUrls():
                for url in md.urls():                   
                    obj.setText(url.path())
                    break
            event.accept()
        return False

class root_App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(root_App, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.lineEdit_1.installEventFilter(QDropHandler(self))

if __name__=="__main__":
    app= QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=root_App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and my ui-xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>758</width>
    <height>424</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="acceptDrops">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_1">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>40</x>
     <y>140</y>
     <width>691</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: i've used qurl::path() and qurl()::toLocalFile(). Results are the same. But ::host() returns the string i want: file:///D:/Qt. i can't understand, why path() returns that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `QLineEdit` class already supports dragging and dropping urls. Your custom handler doesn't fully override that, so that explains why the text is being entered twice. To fully override the default behaviour, your event-filter must return `True` - meaning: yes, I've dealt with this event, so there's nothing more to do.

Your example code can be simplified to this:

```
class root_App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(root_App, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.lineEdit_1.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QEvent.Drop and
            source is self.lineEdit_1):
            md = event.mimeData()
            if md.hasUrls():
                source.setText(md.urls()[0].path())
                return True
        return super(root_App, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

Comment: It works, and i ve applied it to a general "Handler" rather than a specified. Thanks! But the "path()" returns a url without file://. it means the result is /D:/xyz. Because the url contains host and path and "host" of local file is "file://"?

Comment: forget the comment... path always starts by a slash, according to RFC2396.